# How to solve that recurence by itrative method ....?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have tried but faild to find big o of 
T(n)=3t(n/3)+n/lg(n)
Can anyone please give me a solution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, This isn't very clear what you're asking. Post any code you have already tried. Also, check this post out to see how to get fast answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is probably more suited to math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to visualize this problem is a Recursive Tree Diagram.

[The first three levels of the tree are drawn here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PksDy.jpg)

For the first level, we have a total work of `n / lg n`

For the second level, we have 3 calls of `(n/3) / lg (n/3)`. Summing these calls gives a total work of `n / lg (n/3)` at this level.

For the third level, we have 9 calls of `(n/9) / lg (n/9)`. Summing these calls gives a total work of `n / lg (n/9)` or `n / lg (n/3^2)` at this level.

The recursive calls will continue until we have a call of T(1). This condition is met at `n/3^k = 1` or `k = log3(n)`

So now we have a simple summation of all of the levels equal to [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8xt1.jpg)

n is a constant and can be pulled out of the equation. Expanding the summation then gives [this equation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lnRr.jpg)

We can simplify this summation [as shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLlwJ.jpg)

In Big Theta, the summation can be simplified to `Θ(n*(1+log(logn))` as the summation is a harmonic series.

Simplifying further, we have `Θ(n+n*log(logn))` and due to the rules of Big Theta, we can simplify to a final Big Theta of `Θ(nlog(logn))` as the first n will grow at a slower rate and doesn't really matter in our final equation.

But wait! You asked for Big O. Thankfully, Big Theta provides both an upper and lower bound for the problem. Big O only provides an upper bound. What does this mean for us? Big Theta actually is Big O, but not the other way around allowing you to say that the recurrence relation is `O(nlog(logn))`.

Hope this helps!